# AWS S3 static website gives Access Denied

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, web-hosting, cname, namecheap

I am trying to host a static website on S3 with NameCheap DNS, but I can't get it working even if I followed the amazon documentation and some step by step guides such as this one: https://dev.to/sudhachandranbc/host-static-website-in-s3-with-namecheap-dns-2ioc

The problem is that when I'm trying to access my website by using the Redirect URL it shows:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>947BCD1082AC60B7</RequestId>
  <HostId>19u196iwhsacEh5t+A7IFZVcXNU13ad8QE9zLoyIsYCc8hOL2lQISJjmPNDyWXoj6Vr1i2z97Ss=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is my DNS configuration in NameCheap:
[image]

This is the information related to the S3 bucket:
Bucket name: [www.mysite.cc](http://www.mysite.cc)
Access: all set to Public
Static website hosting: Enabled
Hosting type: Bucket hosting
Bucket website endpoint: http://www.mysite.cc.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.mysite.cc/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The website loads fine when I'm using the Bucket endpoint, but it shows that `AccessDenied` message if trying to use the Redirect URL (http://www.mysite.cc)

Is there anything I am missing?